# I can't access the recovery options pressing Shift in the GRUB

Tags: grub2

I recently bought a used Toshiba ac100, with lubuntu 12.10 preinstalled.
The problem is that the previous owner has lost the password, so I am unable to connect to WiFi, change user etc.

I have read the password recovery tips, and stumbled upon another problem: **the shift key doesn't bring up recovery mode options at startup.** I tried pressing it repeatedly, holding it at different times, but with no result.

It just goes from the Toshiba splash screen to Lubuntu at once (no dual boot).
Also I am unable to edit grub from within lubuntu, since I lack the password. 
Live cd won't help, as this laptop has no disc drive.

Comment: You can reset the password quite easily.  See: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/107450)

Answer (score 1):

You can unhide the boot menu just configuring the GRUB files correctly. With a Live USB open the terminal, then type `sudo blkid`. You will get a output similar to this:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="bf554a2f-a035-4c22-bca8-162def35a03c" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="3962db06-3776-4f38-8ab9-eab6feeccc1d" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="75a0854b-8b6b-453f-8aec-2a081a1f19e3" TYPE="swap"
```

Here you can see that my Hard Drive is in the `sda` and my pendrive is `sdg`. We are interested in sda. Now lets look at the descriptions of the partitions. We want the partitions that are ext4. In my case I have two ext4 partitions. This is because I have my `/boot` separated, I will take note about that, but lets assume that you don't have `/boot` separated for now and that your `/` (root) is `sda1`. Now we will mount sda1.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

**Important note**: This is the minimum. If you have a `/boot` partition (or any other) separated just mount it the same way, in my case `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot`. Please take note that I used *`/dev/sda2`*, you should change it if using other mount points.

Now we will proceed to CHROOTING the partition:

```
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Once in this step, use `nano /etc/default/grub` and made it looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vesafb.invalid=1 splash quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Ignore any entry that starts with `#` those are comments. Now run:

```
update-grub
```

This will show you the boot menu by default.